# Xamarin UWP get field name into sender

Tags: forms, xamarin, uwp

I am creating a form in Xamarin for UWP and i have this code :

XAML

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
  <Label Text="My Checkbox"
         VerticalOptions="Center"
         TextColor="White"></Label>
  <CheckBox x:Name="myCheckbox"
            WidthRequest="150"
            VerticalOptions="Center"
            Color="#ff914d"
            CheckedChanged="Check_Changed"></CheckBox>
  <Label Text="Other Checkbox"
         VerticalOptions="Center"
         TextColor="White"></Label>
  <CheckBox x:Name="otherCheckbox"
            WidthRequest="150"
            VerticalOptions="Center"
            Color="#ff914d"
            CheckedChanged="Check_Changed"></CheckBox>
</StackLayout>
```

And in my CS :
(GET_FIELD_NAME is not like this in my code, i'm asking a method to do that)

```
void Check_Changed(object sender, CheckedChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            switch( GET_FIELD_NAME )
            {
                case myCheckbox :
                    // Update myCheckbox var
                case otherCheckbox :
                    // Update otherCheckbox var
                etc.
            }
        }
```

Because i have tons of checkboxes i don't want tons of different methods but a single one with a switch who update the right var with name getted.
I've looked in 'sender' properties but i found nothing...
How can i get this information : the x:Name of field clicked with only one method for all

Thank you for your help ^^
(sorry for mistakes, english is not my maternal language)

Comment: `Name` is just a XAML helper, it is not an actual property you can access at runtime.  You can repurpose some unused attribute like StyleId for the same purpose

Answer (score 0):

The better way to do this is to define an attached `Tag` BindableProperty like UWP platform control. and specific each CheckBox with tag value in the xaml with the following taghelper.

**attached  class**

```
public class TagHelper
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty TagProperty = BindableProperty.Create("Tag", typeof(string), typeof(TagHelper), null);

    public static string GetTag(BindableObject bindable)
    {
        return (string)bindable.GetValue(TagProperty);
    }

    public static void SetTag(BindableObject bindable, string value)
    {
        bindable.SetValue(TagProperty, value);
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
<StackLayout HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Label
        Text="My Checkbox"
        TextColor="White"
        VerticalOptions="Center" />
    <CheckBox
        x:Name="myCheckbox"
        local:TagHelper.Tag="myCheckbox"
        CheckedChanged="Check_Changed"
        VerticalOptions="Center"
        WidthRequest="150"
        Color="#ff914d" />
    <Label
        Text="Other Checkbox"
        TextColor="White"
        VerticalOptions="Center" />
    <CheckBox
        x:Name="otherCheckbox"
        local:TagHelper.Tag="otherCheckbox"
        CheckedChanged="Check_Changed"
        VerticalOptions="Center"
        WidthRequest="150"
        Color="#ff914d" />
</StackLayout>
```

**Code behind** retrieve tag value with `GetTag` method.

```
private void Check_Changed(object sender, CheckedChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var checkbox = sender as CheckBox;
    var tag = TagHelper.GetTag(checkbox);
    switch (tag)
    {
        case "myCheckbox":

            break;


        case "otherCheckbox":

            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Exactly what i want ! Thank you !